# Reboot the system from an initrd without causing a kernel panic

Tags: debian, kernel-panic, initrd

i want to start a linux kernel over pxe boot, load a very small initram, do some jobs there and reboot the machine.

so my init script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
# used for initramfs
export PATH
. /lib/debian-installer/init-debug
debugshell "just booted"

mount /proc
mount /sys
/lib/debian-installer/start-udev

udhcpc

tftp -l - -r /srv/tftp/welcome_test -g 10.10.10.1
sleep 10

reboot
```

basicily i copied the debian netinstaller script and changed a bit.

the problem is now, if i want to reboot i get this kernel panic:

```
Kernel Panic - not syncing: Attemted to kill init!
```

so how can i just reboot after i did my work on the machine? or do i need to start a seperate script via init?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i just oversaw a fact that i did not spawned any init process yet so i was just running in kernel mode all the time... strange things happen there :D

so i i adjust the script with a

```
exec busybox init
```

and create a `/etc/inittab` rule like

```
::sysinit:/bin/bash /bin/reinstall.sh
```

it works really fine!